# Formatting data for using in Angular material table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of rooms, times and students.

```
const students = ["a", "b", "c"];
const times = ["T1", "T2", "T3"];
const rooms = ["room1", "room2", "room3"];
```

Using the above data, I want to create a table like following. This will be arranged in such a way that every student will appear exam in every room in different time slots.

```
ROOM    T1  T2  T3
room1   a   b   c
room2   c   a   b
room3   b   c   a
```

I have the following function but it does not give me correct result.

```
const students = ["a", "b", "c"];
const times = ["T1", "T2", "T3"];
const rooms = ["room1", "room2", "room3"];

const newArr: any[] = [];
rooms.forEach((room, roomIndex) => {
  newArr.push({
    room: room
  });
  times.forEach((time, timeIndex) => {
    students.forEach(student => {
      const isExist = newArr.find(a => {
        const cond1 = a.room === room && a[time] === student;
        const keys = Object.keys(newArr[roomIndex]);
        const cond2 = keys.find(b => newArr[roomIndex][b] === student);
        const cond3 = newArr.find(a => a[time] === student);
        return cond1 || cond2 || cond3;
      });
      if (!isExist) {
        newArr[roomIndex][time] = student;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Table rendered:

```
ROOM    T1  T2  T3
room1   c   b   a
room2   b   c   
room3   a       c
```

Stackblitz url - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-table-example?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
const slots = [9, 10, 11, 12];
const students = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const rooms = [1, 2, 3, 4]
// rooms 9  10  11  12
//.  1   a.  b  c.  d
//   2.  b   a. d.  c
//.  3.  c.  d. a.  b
//.  4.  d.  c. b   a

const allocations = [];

function allocate() {
  rooms.forEach(room => {
    slots.forEach(slot => {
      students.forEach(student => {
        const isExist = allocations.find(allocation => {
          return (allocation.room === room && allocation.student === student) 
          || (allocation.slot === slot && allocation.student === student) 
          || (allocation.slot === slot && allocation.room === room)
        });
        if (!isExist) {
          allocations.push({
            room,
            slot,
            student
          });
        }
      })
    })
  })
  return allocations;
}
console.table(allocate())
```